# Playing an mp3 sound in a c# console Application

Tags: c#, audio, console-application

I have a connect four game which is fully completed, but to learn new stuff im trying to add sounds for when the counter drops in the hole, I cant understand why i keep getting `FileNotFound` exceptions when i have imported my sounds file to be both in the solution and in the debug file.

this keep crashing:

```
(new SoundPlayer("Clonk.mp3")).Play();
```

I have also tried `.PlaySync()` which gave me the same result

thanks guys!

Comment: Try providing an absolute path first, then using Assembly, find out the current executing assembly path. This will help you determine why it's not finding the Clonk.mp3 file.

Comment: that had the same error

Comment: When I try to use the built in `System.Media.SoundPlayer`. It only allowed me to pass it a `*.wav`. Have you tried a `.wav` instead of an `.mp3`?

Comment: Thanks guys, post that as an answer and extend it a bit and ill say youve answered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SoundPlayer` only supports certain `.wav` files. Try converting your `.mp3` file into a `.wav` and see if this fixes the problem for you.

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer(string wav).Play();
```